# Search data from serialized column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created table column called `user_ids` which stores php serialized array value. I need to search value from these column. I have tried below code:-

```
SELECT *  FROM event_users WHERE user_ids REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"search value here".*'
```

Comment: This is my 'user_ids' value a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"5";}

Comment: Issues like this is why you should [normalize your database](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead of storing multiple values in a single column.

Comment: The problem with serialized data is that it is almost meaningless outside of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *  FROM event_users WHERE user_ids LIKE '%"search value here"%'
```